# Routing Problems Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

**I'm pretty new to rails and I've created a method in 
posts_controller.rb that contains the following**

```
def update_feeds 
    Post.get_feeds -- works via console 
    @rss_feedsTab = "/admin/posts"
    redirect_to @rss_feedsTab, :notice => 'Feeds Updated successfully'
end
```

**and trying to make it fire in my view with:**

```
<%= link_to 'Update Feeds', :controller => "posts", :action => "update_feeds", :method=>:post %>
```

**and I get a routing error:**

```
No route matches {:action=>"update_feeds", :method=>:post, :controller=>"admin/posts"}
```

I'm really not grasping how this whole routing works at all, any help would be appreciated :)

**CONTROLLER=posts rake routes:**

```
admin_post GET    /admin/posts/:id(.:format)      admin/posts#show
            PUT    /admin/posts/:id(.:format)      admin/posts#update
            DELETE /admin/posts/:id(.:format)      admin/posts#destroy
            GET    /admin/posts(.:format)          admin/posts#index {:collection=>{:update_feeds=>:post}}
            POST   /admin/posts(.:format)          admin/posts#create {:collection=>{:update_feeds=>:post}}
            GET    /admin/posts/new(.:format)      admin/posts#new {:collection=>{:update_feeds=>:post}}
            GET    /admin/posts/:id/edit(.:format) admin/posts#edit {:collection=>{:update_feeds=>:post}}
            GET    /admin/posts/:id(.:format)      admin/posts#show {:collection=>{:update_feeds=>:post}}
            PUT    /admin/posts/:id(.:format)      admin/posts#update {:collection=>{:update_feeds=>:post}}
            DELETE /admin/posts/:id(.:format)      admin/posts#destroy {:collection=>{:update_feeds=>:post}}
```

**routes.rb**

```
namespace :admin do

   resources :users,:videos,:posts,:links,:rss_feeds

   resources :posts, :collection => {:update_feeds => :post}

end
```

Comment: Can you post your `routes.rb` and the output of `rake routes`?

Comment: updated main post with that info :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you would do well to pay attention to two things here:

1) The method's name in the controller must match the view's name. That is one of the conventions of Rails. For instance, an `index` method in `posts_controller.rb` (`posts#index` for short) will automatically look for a view called `posts/index.html.erb`.

2) Also, your routes establish which names you should use for your controller methods (also called controller actions). Those names are based upon the HTTP verbs (index, new, create, edit, update, show, destroy). So, controller actions are also not named randomly. I would suggest that you work from one of the existing actions listed in your routes.

Rails does allow you to easily create your own actions with the names you want, but you should probably play by the conventions first, and only then try to begin customizing things.

That particular error message you're getting means there is no route associated with the controller action you just created. As I said, creating controller actions involves creating associated views and routes -- and that's why I discourage you to do so at this point. Start from the routes, look at which ones you have and go from there.

Comment: It looks like the OP wants a button/link on a page that triggers a side-effect (server side feed refresh) and redirects back to a main page. Which existing action should be used for that?

Comment: As far as I can tell, if we're looking at a list of posts, it might go into the index action. But I'm not sure I'm comfortable with this data structure. If we're updating feeds, then why don't we have a Feed model instead of a Post model?

Comment: What I've done is created a feed model that contains a list of URLS to fetch feeds from, 

The reason I'm triggering this on the posts page, is that I wanted to have a button that once clicked just cycles through the feeds and adds all those entries to the database and then returns you to the posts page to view all the new posts.

That said, I'm normally used to doing most stuff like this via js and html, and very new to rails, not really sure I'm grasping how to trigger functions like that.

Comment: How did you end up coding that `get_feeds` method that you say works in console? Are you following a tutorial? Did you watch the Railscasts episode on Feed Parsing? http://railscasts.com/episodes/168-feed-parsing

Comment: Yeah I did that tutorial then modified it to take a list of rss urls from another model, and that part all works just great, I can fire it from the terminal no problem and it fills my database with posts from all the RSS feeds, but I don't want it to update the feeds on a cron or anything like that.

basically I want a button, that when clicks updates the feeds 
I'

Comment: it was specifically part 2 of this that got the checkmark 

I set up a controller, and routed what I wanted to happen through the index action 

However, seems to me a separate controller for any function I'd like to fire will be a bit much ? is that the proper way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Routing matches URL paths to controller actions.  The logic is as follows:

1. User navigates to http://your.domain.com/some/path
2. You have something in your `routes.rb` saying `get '/some/path', to: posts#update_feeds`
3. Because the user navigated to /some/path, the update_feeds action in the PostsController gets executed.
4. Controller actions usually either redirect the user to another path (or URL external to your domain), or render some content.

The problem you're having is your `link_to` needs to link to a URL or path, i.e. something that would make sense as the `href` value of an `a` tag.  Rails sometimes gives you route helpers, which are just a convenience.  They allow you to say things like `admin_post_path(3)` instead of `/admins/post/3`.  In your `rake routes`, it doesn't appear you have a nicely named path for your `update_feeds` action.

Change your `routes.rb` to have something like this instead:

```
resources :posts do
    collection do
        post :update_feeds
    end
end
```

This will route /posts/update_feeds to the appropriate controller and action, and give you a route helper so you can change your `link_to` to say:

```
<%= link_to 'Update Feeds', update_feeds_posts_path, method: :post %>
```

Comment: I'm not ignoring your reply :) I've been playing around with some things and trying to grasp it well enough to reply and have some clue what I'm looking at :P

Comment: Check out the edited version, it fits with what you're already doing in your routes.rb better.

Comment: Well, I actually think I just got it working.
I created a controller called feeds_controller.rb and in the def index I put my function, redirect etc.. and then added :feeds to my routes.rb and all works as I expected.

:)